# Prevent future unwanted romantic approaches

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

About two and a half months ago I got a senior full-time position in a medium-sized US company. Because this is a software development job, most of my coworkers are male, whereas I'm a female in my thirties and a moderate advocate for feminist perspectives.

I must say, I worried about unwanted attention from them, and sadly that came true -- yesterday one of my male coworkers asked me out. I loudly rejected him.

I'm considering deterrent measures to keep such attempts from being made ever again. At the same time, I'd rather not "run away", as the salary is  competitive, and the office is only half an hour away from home. I contemplated going to HR -- however, that may harm my professional reputation or force me to leave the job.

What should I do to prevent being approached with such intentions in the future?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61112/discussion-on-question-by-melissa-prevent-future-unwanted-approaches). Keep comments on topic please, the goal isn't who can be the most clever, sarcastic, or impolite. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

> What should I do to prevent being approached with such intentions in
>   the future?

I would suggest that your **firmly and politely** decline such invitations.  I would not do anything **loudly** as to draw un-wanted attention to the situation.  I definitely understand your perspective, having a spouse who has experienced similar actions in the workforce.

I don't think there is anything you can do to *prevent such invitations* unless you want to make it known ( true or not ) that you already have a significant other in your life.

Now, if the **same** person persists, this can be construed as *Sexual Harassment*, and you will need to involve your manager and HR to have the idiot removed.  I would suggest you only do this if the attention level warrants such action.

It is also wildly inappropriate, IMHO, for someone who supervises you to extend such an invitation.

Someone asking you out once doesn't warrant such action.

Comment: Work is, at least in part, a social situation. As such, things like asking someone out are routine and normal occurrences between two people. There's no need for anything more than a polite refusal, assuming the request itself was polite.

Comment: @DLS3141 Agreed, if the invitation itself and the response to the invitation are polite, then no big deal whatsoever.

Answer (score 9):

> I'm considering deterrent measures to keep such attempts from being
>   made ever again.
>
> I contemplated going to HR -- however, that may harm my professional
>   reputation or force me to leave the job

I don't know of any realistic deterrent measures to prevent anyone from asking once. Maybe a sign or poster, but probably not.

I suppose you could go to HR and they could warn everybody to avoid asking you out. Certainly that would be rather awkward, but might be the only way to accomplish what you are seeking. And if it doesn't, do you want to stay in this job anyway?

I'm not sure how you have found companies in the past where it was against the rules to ask someone out, or where nobody ever did even if it was permitted. Maybe you can find such a company and repeat that in the future.

Otherwise, polite rejections to anyone who asks you out seems to be your best bet. Eventually, word will get around that you aren't interested and the requests should stop or at least diminish.

Comment: I don't think a poster is a good idea, LOL.  +1 for good solid humor

Comment: I guess OP could send everyone a link to this post, that would be a pretty good deterrent.

Comment: Depending on how strong the overreation was in this case, I'd say most people in the office may already know.